# Prolonged Touch gesture

Tags: xna, windows-phone-8

Im trying to develop my first Windows Phone 8 game using XNA, and want to pick up when a user has their finger held down on the screen for a long period of time. There are some gestures available, such as Tap and Hold:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967546(v=vs.105).aspx

but none of these seem to continuously pick up the event for as long as the user has their finger held down, only the initial event and another for after a second i think.

Does anyone know if there is custom gesture recognition available for this sort of thing or know of a way of getting around this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using gestures, use the raw touch data and process it yourself.

Use `TouchPanel.GetState()` to get the input for the current frame. This comes as a collection of `TouchLocation`s.

Use its `Position`, `Id` and `State` members to check that there is a single touch on the screen, and that it is remaining within some radius of its start point. If it is, then on that frame the touch is being held down.

Comment: Good man Andrew, thanks very much. Ill give that a bash now and let you know how I get on with it!

Comment: thanks andrew, that worked a charm, meant to mark this answer as correct earlier. Ended up going for a really dummed down version in the end, just constantly checking if the 'Prsssed' attribute of 'State' was set or not, but it does the trick. Small bit slow to response the changes in state at times, and you have to kinda drag your finger a little for the phone to recognise that it's pressed, but works good enough for what i need it to do, so thanks again!